# Laravel: Azure AD authentication session is maintained after the logout in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, session

I have configured Azure AD Authentication in Laravel with SocialiteProvider. I am facing one problem, when I logout from the portal, it redirects to the home page, but my session is still maintained when I am trying to login. It looks like the browser is caching the authentication tokens. I have tried Auth::logout() to log out the user from the application, and Session::flush() to remove all session data, including the Azure AD authentication session. Also I have tried the Session::regenerate() method before Session::flush() to regenerate the session ID and delete the old session data. This should prevent any cached authentication tokens from being reused. But still I am getting the problem.
Here is my logout function.

```
   public function adminLogout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->logout();
         // remove user credentials from session
        $request->session()->forget('user');
        Session::regenerate(); // regenerate session ID
        //Flush Session
        Session::flush();
        //Http::post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0');

        
        //Redirect to Login Page
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Here is login function

```
 public function redirectToAzure()
   {
    
    // return Socialite::driver('azure')->redirect();
     return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();

   }

     public function handleAzureCallback(Request $request)
    {
        
        $user = Socialite::driver('azure')->user();

        if($user)
        {
        // store user credentials in session
        $request->session()->put('user', $user);
         // redirect to main dashboard page
        return view('admin.dashboard')->with('user', $user);
       }
       else{
             return redirect('/login');
           }
    }
```

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: **It looks like the browser is caching the authentication tokens**, What you have tried to invalidate the browser cache? The `Session` has nothing to do with the browser cache.